# How exactly binding is done in closures?

Tags: javascript, closures, symbol-table, name-binding

```
function f() { return s; } // works fine though no `s` is defined yet !

var s=1;
f(); // 1

delete s;

var s=2;
f(); // 2 

(function() {
var s=3;
f(); // 2 and not 3 which means lexical scoping is at play (?)
})();
```

first off, you can close over a variable (`s`) which is not yet defined. How is that possible if lexical (static) scoping is used?

second, after deleting the original `s`, `f()` can find the new `s`. Does this mean closures are bound to variable names rather than references or symbol table indexes or something more machine-level? I would expect from e lexical scoping closure to throw an error since the original `s`is deleted. The new `s` just reuses the name and has nothing to do with the original `s`.

And third, the `s` inside the anonymous function scope is not used by `f()`, does this mean indeed lexical scoping is at play?

Comment: I guess we can answer any "closure" question with "hoisting" without even reading them.

Comment: You might find it instructive to try two variations: first, put that code in an IIFE - `(function() { ...code... })();`.  Then, try your original code except with the statement `"use strict";` (just that string constant) at the very top.

Comment: (Actually the `"use strict";` modification is probably the most interesting.)  Anyway yes, it's all about lexical scoping.

Comment: oops actually in strict mode the `delete` statement just won't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is equivalent to

```
var s;
function f() { return s; } // works fine though no `s` is defined yet !

s=1;
f(); // 1

delete s;

s=2;
f(); // 2 

(function() {
var s=3;
f(); // 2 and not 3 which means lexical scoping is at play (?)
})();
```

Javascript variable declarations are hoisted to the top of their scope and are declared then.  They're then defined where the user sets them to be.  So you can reference a javascript variable before its declared in a function scope.

Also note that delete is generally used for properties on an object, not an object declared with var.  Delete in this case has no effect, regardless of closure.  See fiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5xDz/)

Answer (score 3):

> first off, you can close over a variable (s) which is not yet defined
>   ... how is that possible if lexical (static) scoping is used ?

Refer [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

> second, after deleting the original s, f() can find the new s. Does
>   this mean closures are bound to variable names rather than references
>   or symbol table indexes or something more machine-level? I would
>   expect from e lexical scoping closure to throw an error since the
>   original s is delete. The new s just reuses the name and has nothing
>   to do with the original s.

There is no new s, all declarations are hoisted. There is only one s in the end.
Hoisting still applies.

> and third, the s inside the anonymous function scope is not used by
>   f(), does this mean indeed lexical scoping is at play ?

Yes, the s inside the anonymous function is local to it, and in this case the closure formed over the global s.

Comment: I think the "second" is actually due to `delete s` having no effects and not the hoisting as demonstrated in http://jsfiddle.net/F5xDz/